# How can I properly align alternative productions using the syntax package?

Tags: packages, syntax

I'm using the [`syntax`](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mdwtools/syntax.pdf) package to describe a grammar in a document which I'm compiling using `pdftex`. A stripped-down version of my code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{syntax}

\begin{document}
<program> ::= <expr>
    \alt <expr-list>
\end{document}
```

Oddly, when I compile this, I get no errors or warnings, but the left indentation on the `\alt` line is much smaller than what's shown in the documentation.

For reference, here's the indentation (and corresponding code) as shown in the docs:

[image: A BNF description of a grammar taken from the <code>syntax</code> package docs]

... And here's what my code's producing after being run through `pdftex`:

[image]

The only package I can think of which *might* interfere with this is `fullpage`, but commenting out that line in the preamble has no effect.

I've also tried using the `\grammarindent` preamble command, but this didn't have the intended effect; it does modify the indentation of alternate productions (reliably and predictably, at that), but it's a fixed length rather than being aligned vertically with the corresponding `::=`.

How can I get my BNF grammar descriptions to be indented as in the `syntax` package docs?

Comment: The documentation is produced with `\grammarindent` set to 1 inch (see `mdwtools.tex`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the source of the package documentation it seems like the indent in the examples is hardcoded (ie. not calculated from the size of the first keyword). However, the `::=` also respects the indent, so if you make it sufficiently large then the `alt` lines will be properly aligned (although there may be a gap between the first keyword and the first definition).

If you are willing to provide the first keyword as additional argument, then it is relatively simple to compute the proper indent value automatically using the `calc` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{syntax}

\newlength{\myl}

\newenvironment{indentgrammar}[1]
    {\setlength{\myl}{\widthof{#1}+2em}
    \grammarindent\the\myl
    \begin{grammar}}
    {\end{grammar}}

\begin{document}
\grammarindent1.5in
\begin{grammar}
<statement> ::= <ident> ‘=’ <expr>
\alt ‘for’ <ident> ‘=’ <expr> ‘to’ <expr> ‘do’ <statement>
\alt ‘{’ <stat-list> ‘}’
\alt <empty>

<stat-list> ::= <statement> ‘;’ <stat-list> | <statement>
\end{grammar}

\begin{indentgrammar}{<program>}
<program> ::= <expr>
    \alt <expr-list>
\end{indentgrammar}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Notes:

- The 'sufficiently large' option is shown on top, the automatic
  calculation below.
- For the automatic calculation a new environment is defined. With a
  bit of extra trouble you can also change the existing `grammar`
  environment, using `renewenvironment` or the `etoolbox` package.
- An extra 2em is added because `widthof` is somewhat conservative.
- It is probably possible to read the first keyword from the body of
  the environment instead of as an extra argument, but that is left as
  an exercise for the reader :)
- Your MWE doesn't compile because it is missing `\begin{grammar}` and `\end{grammar}`.

Comment: By the way, the documentation is produced loading `mdwtools.tex`, which has the line `\grammarindent1in`

Comment: That's a bit of an odd thing for a documentation author to do, since the docs are supposed to illustrate another package.